# HUD not work in all aplications (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: unity, 12.04, hud

when I want to close Google Chrome at HUD, HUD
does not bring up the command to close the
application. All the commands I've typed in the HUD,
but it all does not work

so, how to restore HUD as before?

Comment: Did you actually enable Unity HUD at all? It is _not_ enabled by default in 12.04. Or am I reading "it all does not work" wrong?

Answer (score 1):

HUD does close Chrome windows. Instead of typing "exit", type "close" and the first item in the dropdown should be "File > Close Tab" and the second should be "File > Close Window". Select the close window option to close that particular Chrome window. From here on, you can simply type "Alt [to invoke HUD] + CW" and it should pull up the first choice as "File > Close Window". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding' the HUD merely creates an index of a program's menu options, and provides a quicker means of executing them (without the effort of having to reach for a mouse and hunt through menus).

Chrome doesn't have a menu option for 'exit' (it exists in the wrench menu, but not the menu bar), so there's nothing for the HUD to work from.